# Accessing Arrays - multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have the following:

**MySQLi**

```
$query = "SELECT company, AVG(q1) AS high_1 FROM tresults;"
$query .= "SELECT company, AVG(q2) AS high_2 FROM tresults;"
```

**Var Dump**

```
array(2) { ["company"]=> string(8) "7yh6t5rf" ["high_1"]=> string(10) "7.65498709" }
array(2) { ["company"]=> string(8) "de4r5tgh" ["high_2"]=> string(10) "9.12375681" }
```

**Code**

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
  do {
    /* store first result set */
      if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          for ($p=1; $p<=20; $p++)
            {
              echo"
                <td class='a25'>"; 
                  echo number_format($row["high_".$p],2);
              echo"</td>"; 
            } 
          $result->free();
        }
      } while ($mysqli->next_result());
    }
  /* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

**Output**

```
<td class='a25'>7.65</td><td class='a25'></td>
```

Basically, the issue I am having is that the code above only echo's `high_1` and not `high_2`.

I cannot fathom why this is happening.  Any suggestions and feedback welcomed.

Comment: where you have echoed `high_2`

Comment: `var_dump($row);` and check if you actually getting it in result records.

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui he does this: `echo number_format($row["high_".$p],2);` to try echo it....

Comment: @Homer_J - could you not do it in a `foreach` loop where you increment an integer value variable to echo `high_*` ?

Comment: Also what does `var_dump($row);` give?

Comment: HI all, thanks for the questions - the `var dump` is shown at the top of the question - that's the output from `var_dump($row)` - also, I clearly echo both `high_1` and `high_2` in the loop, as per the code above.

Comment: It's wierd. `number_format($row["high_".$p],2);` should return 7.65. Also, increase error_level and turn on display errors.

Comment: Apols, it's one of those mornings for me today, clearly.  it does indeed bring back 7.65.  I copied and pasted the number from above, as opposed to the actual output in an effort to be quicker...I'll turn on display errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetch array instead of `fetch_assoc` function, if you have implemented that, and you can access result row by select index

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      echo "<td class='a25'>", 
           number_format($row[1],2),
           "</td>"; 
      $result->free();
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback but I need to use `fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: If you have only 2 type of array keys than you can do echo (isset($row["high_1"]) ? $row["high_1"] : $row["high_2"])

Comment: Thanks again, however, as you can see from the code in the question, I have 20 keys to loop through: `for ($p=1; $p<=20; $p++)`

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to resolve the issue.

So, the solution I've used is one of simply adding everything to a single array that I can use outside of the `while loop`:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
```